# Implement directory uploads with jQuery File Upload and Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to implement directory uploads with jQuery File Upload plugin by Blueimp. Rails 4 is my backend, and for attachments, I'm using Carrierwave.

The issue now is that, the jquery plugin is not able to recognize the folder that I'm uploading. I already have webkitdirectory parameter passed in the input field. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the jQuery File Upload code in application.js:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: "script",
    sequentialUploads: true,
    // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
    // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
    add: function(e, data) {
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", data.files[
                0]))
        data.context.addClass('working');
        //$('.upload-status-box').addClass('working');
        $('#Upload-Bar').append(data.context);
        $('.upload-status-box').show();
        // Listen for clicks on the cancel button
        data.context.find('span.cancel-upload').click(
            function() {
                jqXHR.abort();
                data.context.fadeOut(function() {
                    data.context.remove();
                });
                count = count - 1;
                removeUploadStatusBoxOnCompletion();
            });
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
        count = count + 1;
    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
        if (data.context) {
            $('.upload-status-box').show();
            progress = parseInt((data.loaded / data.total) *
                100);
            var uploadMeta = parseInt(data.loaded / 1000000) +
                "/" + parseInt(data.total / 1000000) +
                " MB - " + progress + "%";
            data.context.find('.progress-bar').css('width',
                progress + '%');
            data.context.find('.status').text(uploadMeta);
        }
    },
    done: function(e, data) {
        console.log(
            'Your files have been uploaded successfully!'
        );
        // alert('Your files have been uploaded successfully! Depending on the file size, you might have to wait for a while before performing any actions.');
        count = count - 1;
        data.context.removeClass('working');
        data.context.find('button.cancel-upload').hide();
        removeUploadStatusBoxOnCompletion();
    }
});
```

And here's my input field:

```
<div class="awesome-file-uploads" id="inline-upload-status">
<%= form_for [myfolder, Myfile.new], html: { multipart: true, :id => "fileupload" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment, multiple: true, id: "fileinput", style: "display:none;", "webkitdirectory"=> "", "directory"=> "" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :myfolder_parent_id, value: myfolder.id %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the code for uploading and processing the files inside the folder:

```
    $('#folderupload').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    NProgress.done();
    var items = e.target.files;
    var paths = ""; //
    // var myfolder_id = $(this).parent();
    for (var i=0, file; file=items[i]; i++) { 
    paths += file.webkitRelativePath+"###";
    } //
    // uploadFiles(items, myfolder_id.data('inside'));
    $("#paths").val(paths);
    $("#folderupload").submit(); //
});
function uploadFiles(items, myfolder_id){
   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data = new FormData();
    paths = "";

    var AUTH_TOKEN = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    data.append('authenticity_token', AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Set how to handle the response text from the server
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        console.debug(xhr.responseText);
    };

    for (var i=0, file; file=items[i]; i++) {
        paths += file.webkitRelativePath+"###";
        data.append(i, file);
    }

    data.append('paths', paths);

    xhr.open('POST', "/myfolders/"+myfolder_id+"/create_from_folder", true);
    xhr.send(this.data);
}
```

Comment: post code, or we'll have no idea what you're trying to do...

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added the code for you!

Comment: Can you clarify what _the jquery plugin is not able to recognize the folder that I'm uploading_ means?

Comment: And is there a specific reason why you're setting up jQFileupload, only to then upload the files manually yourself with `$('#folderupload').change` and `uploadFiles`? Why not use jQFileupload?

Comment: Are you trying to upload an entire folder and its subdirectories or are you trying to specify where they should be uploaded to?

Comment: There are some limits to the HTTP protocol, for safety. Uploading folders requires multi-file-upload, which is against HTTP directives. To my humble knowing, the only way to do this is with an applet. You can't script file uploads.

Comment: @KarthikK some feedback would be nice — you have to help us help you…

Comment: You can check this link https://protonet.info/en/blog/html5-experiment-drag-drop-of-folders/ It is for plupload plugin but maybe you will find some inspiration. Also keep in mind that webkitdirectory is experimental feature and may just not work properly because of some issue not in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Hi its very easy to use blueimp file upload in rails. Simply you can install gems available for blueimp file upload.Famous are Carrierwave gem & Dragonfly gem. If you have one of this gems , you can use following steps to work on blueimp

Prerequisites

```
have jQuery setup in your app

copy jQuery File Upload files in the proper directories of your Rails app
```

Models
For use with the Carrierwave gem

We'll use basic Carrierwave uploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Let's set up a Picture model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  #one convenient method to pass jq_upload the necessary information
  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:avatar),
      "size" => avatar.size,
      "url" => avatar.url,
      "thumbnail_url" => avatar.thumb.url,
      "delete_url" => picture_path(:id => id),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
end
```

For use with the Dragonfly gem

set up a Picture model (make sure you have both avatar_uid and avatar_name columns in your database)

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  image_accessor :avatar

  #one convenient method to pass jq_upload the necessary information
  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:avatar_name),
      "size" => avatar.size,
      "url" => avatar.url,
      "thumbnail_url" => avatar.thumb('80x80#').url,
      "delete_url" => picture_path(:id => id),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
end
```

Controller

First one controller to handle the downloads: (html response is for browsers using iframe sollution)

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
    render :json => @pictures.collect { |p| p.to_jq_upload }.to_json
  end

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])
    if @picture.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {  
          render :json => [@picture.to_jq_upload].to_json, 
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json {  
          render :json => [@picture.to_jq_upload].to_json           
        }
      end
    else 
      render :json => [{:error => "custom_failure"}], :status => 304
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    render :json => true
  end
end
```

And it's routes:

resources :pictures, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]

Let's play

In whatever view file you want, copy paste this code and enjoy.

```
<h2><%= t('photos.title') %></h2>
<%= form_for Picture.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <div class="span5">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
        </table>
    <% end %>
<script>
  var fileUploadErrors = {
    maxFileSize: 'File is too big',
    minFileSize: 'File is too small',
    acceptFileTypes: 'Filetype not allowed',
    maxNumberOfFiles: 'Max number of files exceeded',
    uploadedBytes: 'Uploaded bytes exceed file size',
    emptyResult: 'Empty file upload result'
  };
</script>

<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>



<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.widget.js' %>
<!-- The Templates and Load Image plugins are included for the FileUpload user interface -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.iframe-transport.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fileupload.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fileupload-ui.js' %>
<!-- add include_tag js files to config.assets.precompile in ...environments/production.rb if you have it in vendor/ assets -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload();
        // 
        // Load existing files:
        $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
          var fu = $('#fileupload').data('blueimp-fileupload'), 
            template;
          fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
          template = fu._renderDownload(files)
            .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
          // Force reflow:
          fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
            template[0].offsetWidth;
          template.addClass('in');
          $('#loading').remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with a custom server-side upload handler

1. Implement a file upload handler on your platform (Ruby, Python, Java, etc.) that handles normal form based file uploads and upload it to your server. See also the Server-side specific tutorials on the [Documentation Homepage.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)
2. [Download](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/releases) and extract the plugin archive.
3. **Edit main.js and adjust the url option to the URL of your custom file upload handler**. Alternatively you can remove the url option and edit index.html and adjust the action attribute of the HTML form element to the URL of your custom file upload handler. If your upload handler requires another parameter name for the file uploads than files[], you also have to adjust the file input name attribute or set the paramName option (see Options documentation).
4. Upload the jQuery-File-Upload folder to your website.
5. Extend your custom server-side upload handler to return a JSON response akin to the following output:

You can see the Output format by going to https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup